# Como tornar visível um item do menu na toolbar ao clicar em um já existente?

Tags: android, menu, actionbar

Tenho um menu na minha toolbar, ele possui as seguintes actions:

- `R.id.action_editar`
- `R.id.action_salvar`

Como posso fazer para que quando eu clicar na action editar, o botão da action salvar se torne visivel?

Isso teria que ser realizado no método onOptionsItemSelected()?
Pois não consigo chamar meu menu nele para definir a segunda action como visível, há alguma forma de fazer isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, isso deve ser feito no método `onOptionsItemSelected()` mas antes terá de obter e guardar uma referência ao MenuItem *salvar* no método `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
//Variável para guardar o MenuItem salvar
MenuItem actionSalvar;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.seu_menu, menu);

    //Guarda a referência
    actionSalvar = menu.findItem(R.id.action_salvar);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.action_editar:
        ...
        ...
        //Torna visível
        actionSalvar.setVisible(true);
    break;
    case R.id.action_salvar:
        ........
        ........
        //Torna invisível
        actionSalvar.setVisible(false);
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ramaral, funcionou perfeitamente!